# Is it possible to automatically transform a phone number before calling it?

Tags: phone-app, copy-paste, text-editor

So I want some kind of solution to take a phone number from my call list, contacts or anywhere else, then transform it in a specific way and then add some digits and symbols in front of the number and a symbol after the number, and then forward the newly created number to the dialer.

For example, I have a phone number in my call list "+37066611111", if I share it as a number in my dialer app (DW contacts and dialer), I get this kind of text:

```
Contact name:
+37066611111
```

I want some kind of tool to get this text, drop this part:

```
Contact name:
+370
```

Then add additional symbols and digits to the remaining number "66611111", so that the result would look like this:

```
866622222,789#9#0866611111#
```

Then pass this newly created number back to the dialer. Is it possible?

I'm using a bootleggers [ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/orig-development/rom-bootleggers-rom-moto-e-2015-lte-t3725351) (Android 9 pie) installed on a Motorola Moto E 2015 phone.

Answer (score 1):

Not all requirements of the question are met in this answer, but this is as close as I got so far, and I'm quite happy with it.

So, this requires to copy the telephone number without the contact name, like this:

```
+370 666 11111
```

Next, I used tasker to create a task which reads the number from the clipboard, loses the "+370" and spaces and then adds the additional digits and symbols.

I used the "Variable set" action to set a new variable to %CLIP (this way the copied number in a clipboard is saved to a separate variable, so we can manipulate it further).

```
Name:
%nr
TO:
%CLIP
```

Then I used "Variable  Search Replace" action on the new variable to get rid of "+370". Took me some time to find out how to get rid of the "+" symbol, because tasker doesn't search for "+" in this action, so I used "\D" in the search parameter, which finds any symbols that are not digits, so it worked for me.

```
Variable:
%nr
Search:
\D370
Replace Matches: checked
Replace with:
08
```

Then another "Variable  Search Replace" with a space in the search parameter to get rid of the spaces. (the "replace matches" must be checked to delete the found text from the variable)

```
Variable:
%nr
Search:
 
Replace Matches: checked
Replace with:
```

Then a "Variable set" action to create a new variable with the additional digits and symbols

```
Name:
%nrr
TO:
866622222,789#9#%nr#
```

And lastly - the "System > Set Clipboard" action to copy the transformed number back to clipboard, so I can use it anywhere I like.

```
Text:
%nrr
```

Then I created a button in the quick settings to launch this task, so all I have to do is copy the tel. no. which I want to transform, use the quick settings button for the task and paste the new number to my dialer app. Originally I wanted Tasker to forward the new number for the dialer to call, but if I use the "Call" action in tasker, everything after the comma in the new number is not forwarded to the dialer. So pasting the number is good enough for me.

I understand that not many people may want this functionality, but if I help even one, I'm happy. I'm willing to edit the answer so it would be easier to understand, but please tell me how to improve it in that case.